# How to left align column entries in an email generated by SQL+HTML script

Tags: html, css, sql-server

I am using SQL+HTML script to send an email containing top 5 columns of a table `mytable`. Currently, I have all the column titles aligned centrally and each column entries aligned to the right using `[th]` and `[td]` repsectively. How can I make entries in `Vendor` column left aligned while keeping everything else the same?

```
  DECLARE @dt datetime, @prev_dt datetime      
  SELECT @dt = dbo.GetDateOnly(getdate())           
  SELECT @prev_dt = dbo.GetDateOnly(getdate()-1)

 SELECT top 5 
  Vendor,  
  OUTL_New_$,  
  OUTL_Old_$,   
  Outl_Diff_$  ,   
  OUTL_Diff_Perc,  
  Analyst  
  into #vpositive  
  FROM mytable   
  ORDER BY 4 DESC
  --select * from #vpositive

    if(@@ROWCOUNT>0)
        begin
            --drop table #email
            DECLARE @Body2 varchar(max)
            declare @TableHead2 varchar(max)
            declare @TableTail varchar(max)
            Set @TableTail = '</table></body></html>';

  Set @TableHead2 = '<html><head>' +
            '<hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;">'+
            '<H5 style="color: #000000; font-family:Arial">2: VENDOR LEVEL TOP 5 OUTL $ <font color="blue">INCREMENTS -</font></H5>' +
            '<style>' +

            'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:10pt;color:Black;text-align:right;font-family:Arial;} ' +
            'th {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:10pt;color:Black;text-align:center;font-family:Arial;} ' +

            '</style>' +

            '</head>' +
            '<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=auto>' +


            '<tr bgcolor=#007336>'+
            '<th><b><font color="white">Vendor</font></b></th>' +
            '<th><b><font color="white">OUTL$ New</font></b></th>' +
            '<th><b><font color="white">OUTL$ Old</font></b></th>' +
            '<th><b><font color="white">OUTL$ Diff</font></b></th>' + 
            '<th><b><font color="white">OUTL$ Diff Perc</font></b></th>' + 
            '<th><b><font color="white">Analyst</font></b></th></tr>';

            --Select information for the Report-- 
            Select @Body2= (select 
                        substring(Vendor,1,60) As [TD]
                        ,'$ '+substring(parsename(convert(varchar,convert(money,cast(OUTL_New_$ as int)),1),2),1,13) As [TD]
                        ,'$ '+substring(parsename(convert(varchar,convert(money,cast(OUTL_Old_$ as int)),1),2),1,13) As [TD]
                        ,'$ '+substring(parsename(convert(varchar,convert(money,cast(OUTL_Diff_$ as int)),1),2),1,13) As [TD]
                        ,substring(CAST(OUTL_Diff_Perc AS varchar(10)),1,4)+' %' As [TD]   
                        ,substring(Analyst,1,20) As [TD]

            from #vpositive
            For XML raw('tr'), Elements)

            Set @Body = @TableHead2 + @Body2 + @TableTail

            --Email
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @recipients='abc@abc.com',
            @subject = My analysis',
            @body = @Body,
            @body_format = 'HTML'; 
        end
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this:

```html
<th align="left">
```

or this:

```css
text-align: left;
```